# Is there any deep learning work using unit norm constraints?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, normalization, keras

I am currently trying to develop an architecture that could benefit from a unit norm constraint on the convolutional weights. I saw in [keras docs](https://keras.io/constraints/#unitnorm), that this constraint was available. Therefore I wondered if any work had used it before, so that I can see how they used it and if they had any difficulty using it (I didn't find any googling it, the paper on weights normalization actually being reparametrization).

I am especially asking because I had tried before without using the constraint, instead implementing a custom callback normalizing the weights. Training was very inefficient, and I think it's mainly because the Adam optimizer isn't optimized for projected gradient descent as explained in this [maths SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1921014/409204).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07868.pdf

Comment: This paper actually isn't about norm constraints it's a simple reparametrisation. The title is very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found one that uses unit norm constraints and a custom optimisation algorithm: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00447 .

The custom algorithm they use is called Inertial Incremental Proximal Gradient. From what I understand, it's basically a stochastic projected gradient descent with dynamic momentum.

However, their implementation wasn't using keras, and I don't know whether they tried to see if they could use other type of optimisation algorithms (I am going to ask them).